# mercurial-server: Password is asked for ssh

Tags: mercurial, ssh, debian, ssh-keys, mercurial-server

I'm trying to manage my mercurial repos on my server (Debian Lenny) with mercurial-server from LShift. I was using this tutorial: http://kurtgrandis.com/blog/2010/03/20/gitosis-for-mercurial/

But when I try to clone the hgadmin repo, ssh asks me for a password.

```
hg clone ssh://hg@MyMercurialServer/hgadmin
```

But I never had set a password for the hg user. It was created using the apt-get installation.
Normally, the authentication should be done with my public ssh key (which was copied to the keys/root directory from mercurial-server). But it seems, that mercurial-server don't uses my public key.
I also flushed the privileges with

```
sudo -u hg /usr/share/mercurial-server/refresh-auth
```

After copying the public key to the mercurial-server keys/root dir. Furthermore, I can't find any logfiles for mercurial-server.
Does anybody know, how to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: start your examinations with `ssh hg@MyMercurialServer`. When you get it worked - come back to mercurial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zerkms, is correct -- debug the ssh directly first.  Try something like:

```
ssh -v -v hg@MyMercurialServer
```

That'll let you know if your key is being sent and rejected or not sent.  Also try adding `-i path/to/private/key` on the client to force sending the key.

The usual config problem in ssh key setups is permissions on the authorized_keys file on the ssh server side.  It needs to be `0600` and the directory its in needs to be `0700`.  You can debug that stuff in `/var/log/messages` on the server side, where sshd will print a message if it's unwilling to trust the authorized_keys file due to permissions.

Comment: thx zerkms and Ry4an, I solved it. The problem was, that I defined in the sshd_config a AllowUsers flag, in which the hg user wasn't listet. By the way, on debian ssh logs into /var/log/auth.log